# How to measure server performance in joomla (not from outside)?

Tags: joomla-api, performance

I am wondering if where is a option to measure the joomla performance on the api level.

something like this (afaik it is profiling)

```
Time:  56.14 ms /  56.14 ms     Memory: 0.593 MB /  0.81 MB     afterLoad   
Time: 149.40 ms / 205.54 ms     Memory: 3.671 MB /  4.48 MB     afterlnitialise     
Time:  30.41 ms / 235.95 ms     Memory: 1.479 MB /  5.96 MB     afterRoute  
Time:  22.22 ms / 258.17 ms     Memory: 0.513 MB /  6.47 MB     beforeRenderComponent com_content   
Time: 141.23 ms / 399.40 ms     Memory: 3.234 MB /  9.70 MB     afterRenderComponent com_content    
Time:   4.63 ms / 404.03 ms     Memory: 0.155 MB /  9.86 MB     afterDispatch   
Time:  13.57 ms / 417.59 ms     Memory: 0.269 MB / 10.13 MB     beforeRenderModule mod_menu (Main Menu)     
Time:  14.40 ms / 431.99 ms     Memory: 0.158 MB / 10.29 MB     afterRenderModule mod_menu (Main Menu)  
Time:   0.37 ms / 432.36 ms     Memory: 0.000 MB / 10.28 MB     beforeRenderModule mod_menu (All Front End Views)   
Time:  37.42 ms / 469.79 ms     Memory: 0.220 MB / 10.50 MB     afterRenderModule mod_menu (All Front End Views)    
Time:   0.17 ms / 469.96 ms     Memory: 0.000 MB / 10.50 MB     beforeRenderModule mod_menu (A Deep Menu)   
Time:   2.52 ms / 472.48 ms     Memory: 0.016 MB / 10.51 MB     afterRenderModule mod_menu (A Deep Menu)    
Time:   0.12 ms / 472.60 ms     Memory: 0.000 MB / 10.51 MB     beforeRenderModule mod_menu (This Site)     
Time:   3.16 ms / 475.76 ms     Memory: 0.009 MB / 10.52 MB     afterRenderModule mod_menu (This Site)  
Time:   0.10 ms / 475.86 ms     Memory: 0.000 MB / 10.51 MB     beforeRenderModule mod_login (Login Form)   
Time:  24.71 ms / 500.58 ms     Memory: 0.570 MB / 11.08 MB     afterRenderModule mod_login (Login Form)    
Time:   0.32 ms / 500.89 ms     Memory: 0.001 MB / 11.08 MB     beforeRenderModule mod_breadcrumbs (Breadcrumbs)    
Time:   4.11 ms / 505.00 ms     Memory: 0.057 MB / 11.11 MB     afterRenderModule mod_breadcrumbs (Breadcrumbs)     
Time:   0.47 ms / 505.48 ms     Memory: 0.000 MB / 11.11 MB     beforeRenderModule mod_menu (All Modules)   
Time:  20.33 ms / 525.80 ms     Memory: 0.120 MB / 11.23 MB     afterRenderModule mod_menu (All Modules)    
Time:   0.16 ms / 525.96 ms     Memory: 0.000 MB / 11.22 MB     beforeRenderModule mod_syndicate (Syndicate Feeds)  
Time:   2.18 ms / 528.14 ms     Memory: 0.014 MB / 11.23 MB     afterRenderModule mod_syndicate (Syndicate Feeds)   
Time:   0.16 ms / 528.30 ms     Memory: 0.000 MB / 11.23 MB     beforeRenderModule mod_tags_similar (Similar Tags 2)    
Time:   9.84 ms / 538.14 ms     Memory: 0.169 MB / 11.40 MB     afterRenderModule mod_tags_similar (Similar Tags 2)     
Time:   0.61 ms / 538.74 ms     Memory: 0.000 MB / 11.40 MB     beforeRenderModule mod_menu (Top)   
Time:   4.87 ms / 543.61 ms     Memory: 0.025 MB / 11.42 MB     afterRenderModule mod_menu (Top)    
Time:   0.22 ms / 543.83 ms     Memory: 0.000 MB / 11.41 MB     beforeRenderModule mod_search (Search)  
Time:   4.13 ms / 547.96 ms     Memory: 0.026 MB / 11.44 MB     afterRenderModule mod_search (Search)   
Time:   5.43 ms / 553.39 ms     Memory: 0.139 MB / 11.58 MB     afterRender
```

and this

[image: overall exec time and memory usage]

to be clear, here I do not reference how to measure the remote calls via http, which are obvious to do with browsers dev tools or with any network performance measuring tool. Here is the internal measuring of the joomla on the server via php or joomla means ment.
Afaik it has the same naming as in different languages: I would like to be able to profile a running joomla instance. But how?

Comment: The question isn't very clear. You're already familiar with profiling information. Are you asking how to get this information through code? Or how to add custom marks in your extensions?

Comment: @Sharky I am not familiar with the options existing either in joomla or anything other. So here I am asking how to get these details, which I have found from research on the internet what I exactly need for a better analysis. I have also updated my question to match to your questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show profiling information in Joomla, enable `Debug System` option in Global Configuration, enable `System - Debug` plugin and enable `Show Profiling` option in plugin's configuration.